# Getting a blank page on deploying the app on github

Tags: reactjs

I have created an expense tracker app and it works error free in development. Problem is that I could not deployed it in github. I followed following steps to deploy and it works fine when i deployed other apps.
added gh-pages using `yarn add gh-pages`

```
"homepage": "https://githubusername.github.io/expense-tracker"
"predeploy": "yarn run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
git add status
git add .
git commit 
and push origin master
```

Now i can see only a blank page when i open the url where app is deployed and when i inspect there few errors like;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

https://github.com/sohailshams/expense-tracker

deployed url: https://sohailshams.github.io/expense-tracker/

In development there is no error can anyone please help me to deploy this app and help me to fix the issues.

Comment: On line 16 of this [file](https://github.com/sohailshams/expense-tracker/blob/master/src/context/GlobalState.js) what you return does not suppose to be a JSON with the transactions' object as key if it's not present on the localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Navigating through the code I found that you are not returning the right value on [this function](https://github.com/sohailshams/expense-tracker/blob/059598b37402c063bc291bce75bfcfa62ab316ff/src/context/GlobalState.js#L13). I tried loading what is your initialState on the local storage under the key "state" and it worked perfectly.

So the correct solution would be

```js
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState, (emptyState) => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('state');
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : emptyState;
  });
```

I think that the main issue is related to the fact that you are expecting an object with the transaction's key but instead you are passing an empty array.

Please, let me know if it doesn't work. I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The init function you pass to `useReducer` should accept as the first argument the `initialState` and return that if nothing is found in the `localStorage`.

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState, (initial) => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('state');
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : initial;
  });
```

See the [lazy-initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization) (*which is the syntax you use*)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)